# Duvida na ligação de duas tabelas para trazer na view

Tags: c#, comandos

Tenho uma tabela Marca e uma tabela Modelo, onde na hora de listar todas as marcas eu consigo trazer do banco e mandar para o meu `controller`, só que no momento que faço a pesquisa para listar os Modelos e mostrar na minha `view` os modelos e suas respectivas marcas, não consigo, a parte das marcas fica em branco e só consigo trazer os modelos.

Minha classe de Marca:

```
public class clsMarca
{
   [Key]
   public int marIdMarca { get; set; }

   [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe o nome da marca")]
   [MinLength(3), MaxLength(50)]
   [Display(Name = "Marca")]
   public string marMarca { get; set; }

   public virtual ICollection<clsModelo> Modelos { get; set; }
}
```

Minha classe de modelos:

```
public class clsModelo
    {
        [Key]
        public int modIdModelo { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage="Informe o nome do Modelo")]
        [Display(Name = "Modelo")]
        [StringLength(40, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "O nome do modelo precisa ter no mínimo 3 letras")]
        public string modModelo { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Marca")]
        public int modIdMarca { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("modIdMarca")]
        public virtual clsMarca Marca { get; set; }

        List<clsModelo> lstModelo { get; set; }
    }
```

Meu comando SQL na classe repositório para  trazer todos os modelos do banco

```
public List<clsModelo> listar()
        {
            strQuery = "select * from tblModelo mode join tblMarca mar on mar.marIdMarca = mode.modIdMarca";
            List<clsModelo> lstModelo = db.Database.SqlQuery<clsModelo>(strQuery).ToList();
            return lstModelo;
        }
```

Ja tentei com varias formas de fazer o comando SQL mas nenhum adiantou:

```
 //strQuery = "select modModelo, (select marMarca from tblMarca) from tblModelo";
 //strQuery = "select modModelo, modIdMarca from tblModelo";
 //strQuery = "select mode.modModelo, mar.marMarca from tblModelo mode left join tblMarca mar on mar.marIdMarca = mode.modIdMarca";
```

E sempre mostra assim na view: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Obs.: Estou usando o Entity Framework e no padrão MVC
Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Neste caso acho que não está é a conseguir fazer o __match__ entre o resultado da consulta e o objeto `clsMarca` do tipo `Marca` (nem sei se isso será possível, pelo menos diretamente).

Comment: E quais seriam minhas alternativas?

Comment: Partindo do princípio que o objeto `db` é do tipo `DbContext`, não seria suficiente fazer `List<clsModelo> lstModelo = db.clsModelo.ToList();`?

Comment: Tentei dessa forma, mas não adiantou muita coisa

Comment: Mas não lhe devolveu todos os modelos? Dentro de cada modelo tem o objeto `clsMarca` que tem a informação da marca. Edita a sua questão e coloque o código que está a usar para criar a lista que tem como imagem (onde não aparece a informação da marca).

Comment: @JoãoMartins, desse modo não retorna nem os modelos, no meu caso estou fazendo a pesquisa no banco, ele esta trazendo os modelos, mas as marcas vem null, e eu não estou entendo o porque disso, e eu consigo trazer o Id da Marca mas não consigo trazer o nome dela. Você consegue me ajudar? Estou fazendo pelo Database-First

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No `foreach` da sua `View`, você precisa chamar a `marMarca` de dentro da `Marca` do `item` do seu `foreach`

Assim:

```
<td>
   @item.Marca.marMarca
</td>
```

Comment: Já esta desse modo no meu foreach

Comment: no seu metodo `listar()`, a `marMarca` vem populada? (Caso não saiba como ver, coloca um break point nessa linha `return lstModelo;`, debuga o código, ao chegar nessa linha, clica em cima do `lstModelo` e aperta `Shift + F9`)